# Active Directory errors "The operation failed due to insufficient access rights.", and "Unhandled exception while executing module: replace"

Tags: authentication, ansible, active-directory, winrm

I am using Ansible modules to create users and perform some actions on user accounts in Active Directory. However, I am getting errors for two of my tasks. I wonder if the cause for these two errors are the same.

For the first task shown below, I got this **error: "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: replace."**

```
  - name: Create multiple users
    community.windows.win_domain_user:
      name: "{{ item.PreferredName }}"
      firstname: "{{ item.FirstName }}"
      lastname: "{{ item.LastName }}"
      attributes:
        displayName: "{{ item.PreferredName }}"
      password: "{{ item.password }}"
      password_expired: yes
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      sam_account_name: "{{ item.SamAccountName }}"
      upn: "{{ item.UserPrincipalName }}" 
      domain_username: domain\username
      domain_password: password
      domain_server: domain.local
    with_items: "{{ hostvars.localhost.data_list }}"
    ignore_errors: true
```

This is the second task, I got the **error: "message": "The operation failed due to insufficient access rights."**

```
  - name: Run script
    ansible.windows.win_powershell: 
      script: |     
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [array]
            $datalist
        )

        $results = foreach ($user in $datalist) {
            $path = $user.path
            Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'reddy'" | Disable-ADAccount 
            Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'reddy'" | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $path
            Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'reddy'" -Properties whenChanged,DistinguishedName,MemberOf | Select Name,SamAccountName,Enabled,whenChanged,DistinguishedName,MemberOf 
        }
        $results | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\users.txt   

      parameters:
        datalist: "{{ hostvars.localhost.data_list }}"
      error_action: stop
    ignore_errors: true
```

I checked my Active Directory, the users were created, but with only first name, last name, samaccount name, and upn details. The users were also not disabled and all of them are still in the same OU.

How do I resolve these errors and make the tasks work properly on user accounts in AD?

If I run only these commands, I am able to do it successfully and get an output, C:\users.txt file.

```
  - name: Run script
    ansible.windows.win_powershell: 
      script: |     
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [array]
            $datalist
        )

        $results = foreach ($user in $datalist) {
            Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'reddy'" -Properties whenChanged,DistinguishedName,MemberOf | Select Name,SamAccountName,Enabled,whenChanged,DistinguishedName,MemberOf 
        }
        $results | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\users.txt 

      parameters:
        datalist: "{{ hostvars.localhost.data_list }}"
      error_action: stop
    ignore_errors: true
```

---

I am not sure if it has anything to do with winrm transport details.
The server details as listed in my hosts file:

```
[ADserver]
10.11.18.190

[ADserver:vars]
ansible_user=domain\username
ansible_password=password
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=credssp
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation=true
```